# Architecturing testmode/livemode using OAuth 2 token

Tags: api

The title is a bit obscure. I'm interested about some feedbacks on a specific architecture pattern.

Let's take as an example the Stripe API: when you are using this API, the system is basically broken into two parts: live mode and test mode. If you hit the "/customers" end-point, you can either retrieve test mode customers or live mode customers, based on the type of API key used.

I'm asking myself how I could implement such a pattern using an OAuth 2 access token.

In my workflow, I have a single application page (JavaScript) that communicates through my API. I have a "live"/"test" switch, so basically my whole website is replicated into two distinct environments.

When I log in into my application, my authorization server creates a unique access token (OAuth 2 Bearer token), that is send for each requests. But obviously, my access token is tied to the "session", not an "environment" (live or false), so if I want to implement a switch live mode / test mode, I cannot rely on the token, because the token is "generic".

I've thought about two options:

- Depending on live mode or test mode, I send an additional header to all my request (like X-Livemode which is either true or false). Then, in my back-end, I reuse this header to automatically adds a filter on all my requests.
- If I switch to live mode or test mode, I ask my authorization server another access token. This would means that access token would have additional context information. However this seems a bit complicated, and I'm not sure that OAuth 2 spec allows token to have such additional information.

I'm not sure if this post is clear or not :p.

The second part of the question, is what is the best way to implement such a system where all the resources are basically duplicated between live / test mode ?

In my understand, it should be as simple as adding a "isLivemode" property to all resources, and make sure that all my SQL queries are aware of this. Is this correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution I've used in the past (albeit a bit of a workaround) is just to append "live" or "test" (base64 or hex encoded) to the api key, like so:

Imagine your actual key is:

```
9a0554259914a86fb9e7eb014e4e5d52
```

In your key presentation, present your key to the user as:

```
9a0554259914a86fb9e7eb014e4e5d526c697665
```

Then use a regular expression to strip off the known characters.

Alternatively, if you're equipped to handle key-value maps, a more "OAuth2-spec" approach would be to generate unique keys for live and test and do a key-value map lookup on the request to determine if one belongs to live or test.

Comment: The "test" "live" part in the key sounds like a nice and easy solution, albeit a bit hacky! Thanks!