# Create accounts and API tokens for live mode and test mode

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, architecture, django-rest-knox

I want to create a system that works similar to stripe.
There'll be live API keys, as well as test API keys.
I have been thinking of how to implement this architecture, and I am not sure the best way to go about it. I found a similar question on this but it didn't help much.

[Architecturing testmode/livemode using OAuth 2 token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539688/architecturing-testmode-livemode-using-oauth-2-token)

My current progress is basically:

- I have decided to use https://github.com/James1345/django-rest-knox instead of DRF's default authtoken because knox supports multiple token creation and I thougt I needed that feature.
- I intend to create tokens as `pub_key_<token>` and `test_key_<token>` and remove or strip the prefix before authentication
- I intend to create a LiveAccount Model and a TestAcoount model.

However, after authenticating the request from a test api token, it's unclear how to route or perform requests to TestAcoount instead of LiveAccount.

Please any ideas or a better implementation strategy is highly welcomed

Comment: shouldn't be simpler to create one Model with boolean field `test_account = True/False` ?

Comment: Yeah, that make's sense but users should be able to perform real action that would not import the real account. An example is to credit the account or increase the balance. Users should be able to do so without their actual balance been altered

Comment: I wouldn't share data between both accounts but `TestAccount` should be separated with some money at start. And when you finish work with `TestAccount` then you should create real `LiveAccount` with real money and new `token`.

Comment: Yeah, that's thoughful, thanks